# use paredit key bindings with paredit-everywhere

Tags: paredit

How can I tell paredit-everywhere to use bindings from paredit, 
so I can :

- Use paredit's keybinding without having to redeclare them
- Keep paredit-everywhere shortcuts the same as paredit if I change a shortcut in paredit

[paredit-everywhere.el](https://github.com/purcell/paredit-everywhere/blob/master/paredit-everywhere.el) and paredit use mode-map to define keys.

A better way of formulate my question could be "how to use some paredit mode-map keys in paredit-everywhere mode-map when mode is paredit-everywhere)

I came across [this manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Inheritance-and-Keymaps.html) and came up with this:

```
(when (package-installed-p 'paredit-everywhere)
  (require 'paredit-everywhere)
  (eval-after-load 'paredit-everywhere
    '(progn (set-keymap-parent paredit-everywhere-mode-map paredit-mode-map)
        (define-key paredit-everywhere-mode-map (kbd "(") nil)
        (define-key paredit-everywhere-mode-map (kbd ")") nil)
        (define-key paredit-everywhere-mode-map (kbd "[") nil)
        (define-key paredit-everywhere-mode-map (kbd "]") nil)))
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'paredit-everywhere-mode))
```

which works (but is kinda-hacky) it make the paredit-everywhere-mode-map parent's paredit-mode-map and set the parenthesis, bracet open,close to nil to avoid the extra space added by paredit.

Do not hesitate to share if you have a better solution thus